# Why oauth2 token refresh may issue new refresh token? (is this mitigation of some kind of threat)

Tags: oauth2

During token refresh, the auth server may issue new **refresh** token.

```
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#page-11
...
(H)  The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
        the refresh token, and if valid, issues a new access token (and,
        optionally, a new refresh token).
...
```

This seems so bad for usability.

If some intermittent network failure happens, and new refresh token is not received by the client, then this leaves client with invalid refresh token, requiring new authentication by resource owner.

Does it address some kind of security threat? What kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refresh token is always sent together with the access token which the client requested, so if the client loses network connection before it receives the response, authorization fails anyway. It's not possible to “miss” a refresh token.

As to the purpose of the feature: Whenever the client uses its current refresh token, there's a chance that it gets leaked. It makes perfect sense to allow the server to limit refresh token usage depending on how much risk is considered acceptable. For example, the server may allow a refresh token to be used only once.